# CFML select only 3 int from form.zipcode

Tags: forms, coldfusion, cfml, zipcode

I know this is probably easy but how to would I select only the first 3 digits from a form field called zipcode when I do #form.zipcode#

I would prefer this to be in cfml if possible.

Example 03954 becomes 039

This is for doing shipping calculations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy, use the built-in `left()` function.

Tags:

```
<cfset fullZipCode = trim(form.zipcode) />    
<cfset firstThree = left(fullZipCode, 3) />    
<cfdump var="#firstThree#" />
```

or in `cfscript`

```
<cfscript>    
  fullZipCode = trim(form.zipcode);     
  firstThree = left(fullZipCode, 3);     
  writeDump(var="#firstThree#");
</cfscript>
```

Docs: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3a.html